# What is the opposite to this encryption+compression code in C#?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, encryption, compression

I have written code that encrypts and then compresses data,
but I have a hard time writing code that does everything in reverse.

I get various errors no matter how I assemble the code.

My question is very basic:

In what order should the different bits of code be used?

Here is my sample code for encrypting and compressing:

```
MemoryStream mS = new MemoryStream();
CryptoStream cryptS = new CryptoStream(ms, des.CreateEncryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write));
DeflateStream defS = new DeflateStream(cryptS, CompressionMode.Compress)
BinaryWriter bW = new BinaryWriter(defS))

//bw.Write("write a string for example");

bW.Close();
```

Now, in the decryption routine, should the `CryptoStream` be used after the `DeflateStream` to properly trace the encryption routine backwards?
Or should the `DeflateStream` be used after the `CryptoStream`?

Like the following example:

```
MemoryStream mS = new MemoryStream();
DeflateStream defS = new DeflateStream(ms, CompressionMode.Compress)
CryptoStream cryptS = new CryptoStream(defS, des.CreateEncryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write));
BinaryWriter bW = new BinaryWriter(cryptS))

//bw.Write("write a string for example");

bW.Close();
```

The errors I am getting vary from `Unknown block type. Stream might be corrupted.` to `Bad data`.

**EDIT:**

Here are my encryption and decryption routines.
I get the error `Unknown block type. Stream might be corrupted`.

Encryption routine:

```
using (MemoryStream mS = new MemoryStream())
            {
                using (CryptoStream cryptS = new CryptoStream(mS, dES.CreateEncryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                {
                    using (DeflateStream defS = new DeflateStream(cryptS, CompressionMode.Compress))
                    {
                        using (BinaryWriter bW = new BinaryWriter(defS))
                        {
                            DateTime dT = new DateTime().Now;
                            bW.Write(dt.Ticks);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

Decryption routine (assume that mS is populated with the encrypted data):

```
using (MemoryStream mS = new MemoryStream())
            {
                using (DeflateStream defS = new DeflateStream(mS, CompressionMode.Decompress))
                {
                    using (CryptoStream cryptS = new CryptoStream(defS, dES.CreateDecryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Read))
                    {
                        using (BinaryReader bR = new BinaryReader(cryptS))
                        {
                            DateTime dT = new DateTime((long)bR.ReadInt64());
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

I get the error `Failed to construct a huffman tree using the length array. The stream might be corrupted.`

What might be the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data was compressed, then encrypted, so the first thing you need to do is decrypt it, then you can decompress it. So, yes - it is reversed... but what isn't immediately obvious is that the data flow is also reversed, so the order you chain the streams together remains the same.

It would also be helpful if you wrap your stream usages in `using` blocks to ensure they are flushed and closed correctly.

This code should work:

```
using (var des = new AesCryptoServiceProvider())
{
    byte[] result;

    using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        using (var encryptor = des.CreateEncryptor())
        using (var cryptS = new CryptoStream(ms, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
        using (var defS = new DeflateStream(cryptS, CompressionMode.Compress))
        using (var bw = new BinaryWriter(defS))
        {
            bw.Write("Hello, World.");
        }

        result = ms.ToArray();
    }            

    using (var ms = new MemoryStream(result))            
    using (var decryptor = des.CreateDecryptor())
    using (var cryptS2 = new CryptoStream(ms, decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Read))
    using (var defS = new DeflateStream(cryptS2, CompressionMode.Decompress))
    using (var br = new BinaryReader(defS))
    {
        var x = br.ReadString();
    }
}
```

See [this fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/kCQXuj) for a demo.

Comment: Thank you. Please see my updated question. I added a piece of my code.

Comment: @vaid compare your code to mine. They're different. You have your streams chained differently on write to read.

Comment: hmmmm... Could you elaborate a little bit please?

Comment: @vaid you change the order of deflate and crypto. I don't. As I explained in the text of the answer.

Comment: but you said on your answer that the process needs to be reversed. at encryption I encrypt and then compress, while on the decryption I decompress and then decrypt. right?

Comment: I get the following error when i do it your way: `Block length does not match with its complement.`. What does it mean?

Comment: @vaid I explain the answer that it does need to be reversed but why that means the order has to remain the same. I'm not sure what to suggest re the error - I've given you a working example (as the fiddle demonstrates),. Make changes to it until it doesn't work and provide a [mcve] when you can demonstrates the problem.

Comment: hmmm. This is weird. I've changed my code to match yours but it still doesnt work properly. I will need to investigate more before I edit my question again. I will still accept your answer because it is the correct answer to my formulated question.

Comment: I solved my problem. The problem was that the IV and Key of DES component at decryption must match the IV and Key of DES used in Encryption.

Comment: @vaid yep! Glad it's sorted.

Comment: Kind of still having problems getting the correct values back, but at least I am not getting any weird errors.